# how compile AIDL file with gitlab-ci

Tags: android, docker, aidl

I had to migrate my project to gradle 8. And now I have to specify in my build.gradle to generate the aidl files:

```
buildFeatures {
    aidl = true
}
```

when I build my project from my android sutio I have no problem.
However when the gitlab-ci pipeline generates the release I have this error:

```
Run with --info for a stacktrace.
    - Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
            - Task :app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
            - Task :app:compileDevDebugAidl FAILED
            - Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDevDebug
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugAidl'.
    - A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable
            - A problem occurred starting process 'command '/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/33.0.0/aidl''
    * Try:
    - Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    - Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    - Run with --scan to get full insights.
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
    You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
            See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    BUILD FAILED in 44s
    2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
    Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
    00:00
    ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

here is my gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: $CI_REGISTRY/xxx/devops/gitlabci/android_compiler_jdk17:latest

before_script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

include:
  - '/mkdocs.gitlab-ci.yml'
  - project: 'xxx/devops/gitlabci'
    ref: master
    file: '/android/release.android.gitlab-ci.yml'

assembleDevDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDevDebug --console=plain --no-daemon
  only:
    - develop
    - /^feature/.*$/
```

and my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ARG GITLAB_TOKEN

ENV ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK="33"
ENV ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS="33.0.2"
ENV ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS="9477386_latest"
ENV ANDROID_HOME="$PWD/android-sdk-linux"

RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache add wget tar unzip

RUN wget --quiet --output-document=$PWD/android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
RUN unzip -d ${ANDROID_HOME} ./android-sdk.zip
RUN rm ./android-sdk.zip
# Because sdkmanager need <sdk>/cmdline-tools/latest/ path
RUN mkdir ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest
RUN mv ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/bin ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
RUN mv ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/lib ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/lib

RUN yes | ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"
RUN yes | ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools"
RUN yes | ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}"
RUN yes | ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

RUN mkdir -p ~/.gradle
RUN echo "gitlabToken=${GITLAB_TOKEN}" > ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

RUN export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/
RUN export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

how can i fix my issue?